# Meteor: collection.remove.(id) works but still catching a 500 error

Tags: meteor, try-catch

The item gets deleted/removed from the DB, but the catch error is Internal Server Error.

event triggered:

```
Template.post.events({
 'click .delete': function () {
   Meteor.call("deleteJob", this._id, function (err, result) {
     if (!err) {
       console.log("meteor call to remove job was good");
       Bert.alert("Poof! Job deleted from the site.", "success");
       Router.go('/');
     } else {
       Bert.alert("Rrrrr. No worky.  " + err.reason + "  " + result, "danger");
       console.log("meteor call was bad", err);
     }
   });
 }
});
```

Method call:

```
Meteor.methods({
  deleteJob: function (id) {
    var post = Posts.findOne(id);

    if (post.author !== Meteor.userId()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }

    try {
      var postId = Posts.remove(id);
      return postId;
    } catch (exception) {
      // If an error occurs, return it to the client.
      return exception;
    }
  }

});
```

The remove() in the try should never return if there is a catch, right?

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

I'm using two packages that are checking my arguments. #didntKnow

- check
- audit-argument-checks

Keep an eye on your terminal window, peeps.

I needed this first in my method:

```
check(id, String);
```

Giving me this as the solution:

```
Meteor.methods({
    deleteJob: function (id) {
    check(id, String);

    var post = Posts.findOne(id);

    if (post.author !== Meteor.userId()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }

    try {
      var postId = Posts.remove(id);
      return postId;
    } catch (exception) {
      // If an error occurs, return it to the client.
      return exception;
    }
  }

});
```